# While installing Storm we are getting error that the supervisor hasn't started. What should we do?

Tags: apache-storm

```
 2013-04-04 14:02:39 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 07a06309-95f5-423b-999b-f5913388bb2e still hasn't started
 2013-04-04 14:02:39 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 07a06309-95f5-423b-999b-f5913388bb2e still hasn't started
 2013-04-04 14:02:40 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 07a06309-95f5-423b-999b-f5913388bb2e still hasn't started
 2013-04-04 14:02:40 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 07a06309-95f5-423b-999b-f5913388bb2e still hasn't started
 2013-04-04 14:02:41 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 07a06309-95f5-423b-999b-f5913388bb2e still hasn't started
 2013-04-04 14:02:41 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 07a06309-95f5-423b-999b-f5913388bb2e still hasn't started
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Error.  This message is logged when the supervisor is starting or supervisor is trying to spawn a worker to launch a topology.  Your supervisor process will start eventually.  If it does not start there should be additional log messages to describe the cause for the process not starting.

Comment: there should be an error in ur supervisor logs.  If you do not see an error in your supervisor logs, check stormUI to see if the supervisor is on.  If that is not the case check ur nimbus logs

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612810/exception-after-submitting-topology?noredirect=1#comment53245375_32612810