# exception after submitting topology

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm new in storm and trying to submit a topology and found this 
in supervisor [image]
[image]
I found this in log file of workers

```
 [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at backtype.storm.drpc.DRPCInvocationsClient.<init>(DRPCInvocationsClient.java:23)
    at backtype.storm.drpc.DRPCSpout.open(DRPCSpout.java:69)
    at storm.trident.spout.RichSpoutBatchTriggerer.open(RichSpoutBatchTriggerer.java:41)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3985$fn__3997.invoke(executor.clj:460)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

log file of supervisor

```
supervisor [INFO] ff6460a5-aafb-44a4-a49c-2de945ffd572 still hasn't started
2015-09-15 02:00:54 supervisor [ERROR] Error when processing event
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72)
    at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:149)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:138)
    at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:85)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:134)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:125)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:34)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_.invoke(zookeeper.clj:78)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$mkdirs.invoke(zookeeper.clj:88)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__1996.set_ephemeral_node(cluster.clj:54)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2415.supervisor_heartbeat_BANG_(cluster.clj:300)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
```

and this is in the supervisor log file too

```
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015-09-15 02:00:54 supervisor [INFO] ff6460a5-aafb-44a4-a49c-2de945ffd572 still hasn't started
2015-09-15 02:00:55 ClientCnxn [INFO] Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 20020ms for sessionid 0x14fce3996380015, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-09-15 02:00:58 ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2015-09-15 02:00:58 ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2015-09-15 02:00:59 supervisor [INFO] ff6460a5-aafb-44a4-a49c-2de945ffd572 still hasn't started
2015-09-15 02:01:01 supervisor [INFO] ff6460a5-aafb-44a4-a49c-2de945ffd572 still hasn't started
2015-09-15 02:00:59 util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
```

Comment: is the zookeper running?

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes but i noticed that after time ./zkCli.sh closed is there any way to control the time of connection? i guess that is the reason

Comment: i have this message too in the supervisor connection caution : file name  not matched resources/** !!?

Comment: Did you start Zk server? zkCli.sh is the client.

Comment: yes of course i started server first then client but after some times client closed and server still working !!

Comment: is it happened just as you start the topology ? I would check the spout init method. there are any logs from the spout ?

Comment: this happened just topology is submitted , supervisor gave message that file name is not matched resources /** then gave kill : no such process

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for this issue.

1. zookeeper is not started.
2. CPU get to peak for a while, no heartbeat send in the timeout, so nimbus think the supervisor is dead, the disconnect the connection.
3. worker timeout is too short, maybe the default is 10sec, you can change it to 600 or more to try. it's almost like #2.
4. Make sure nimbus is working fine.
5. worker.childopts is not correct, it means the memory setting is not correct, change the xmx and maxpermsize try again.
6. if you start the storm with winrm or powershell, maybe the default memory is not enough, since the default memory is only 1024M, you need to set more, such as 2048M to try.

Comment: This site supports a rich suite of markup tools for formatting lists; you should use them!